# Gmail constantly "Trying to reconnect..." and "still working"

Tags: gmail, firefox

In the recent weeks, when I open my Gmail account, I constantly get connection problems. Gmail says "something is not right", "trying to reconnect", "still working", etc. This can go on like this for minutes. It becomes impossible to work.

I do not have connection problems in any other website, so it cannot be related to my internet connection.

Is there anything I can do to make my Gmail account work as before?

EDIT: the original problem happened on Firefox, and it persisted after I cleaned the cache. But, in Chromium, Gmail runs just fine. So, the problem is just in the connection between Firefox and Gmail.

Comment: Did you try with other browser. Clear the cache and try.

Comment: @serenesat clearing the cache did not help, but switching from Firefox to Chromium solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I'd uninstall, clean the registry and reinstall if you MUST use FireFox.  I usually use Chrome.  Chrome, by Google, works good for Gmail.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi : I have added the same comment as an answer, if you want you can accept it to close this question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with other browser, it would solve the problem.

Comment: I switched from Firefox to Chromium, and this indeed solved the problem... for exactly two days. Now, I have exactly the same problem in Chromium: "Trying to reconnect...", "Still working..."

Comment: But, after switching to Chrome and using the no-labs link: https://mail.google.com/mail/?labs=0 the problem is apparently solved.